# Error in displaying tab bar controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm developing a project in Swift and when using the storyboard to modify the views, I find an uncomfortable situation. The image is self-explanatory: [Image of the stroyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGDRu.jpg).

As you can see, the bar has grown and it's impossible to see the view i'm working in. At first, the error ocurred in the navigation controller beneath the tab bar controller but now it spreads to the new views I create and connect.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bar has grown"? I'm not sure I understand why it's impossible to see the view you're working in, the canvas can be moved and zoomed in/out...more clarification would be helpful here.

Comment: I mean that the **tab bar** has grown. In the photo you can see some views are entirely blue while they shouldn't (in fact the one on the left is the tab bar view controller). That is the tab bar that has progressively grown upwards each time I re-opened the project. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: I have taken a [snapshot](http://imgur.com/H47B8UI) of a fresh new tab bar project and marked what has grown. The problem is of visualization in the storyboard, in the simulator there's nothing wrong and i can still place labels and so on the view but I can't see clear the things i placed.

Comment: The problem is even more strange. For posting the last comment I created a new project and after that closed the windows (not quitted Xcode), opened the original project again and everything was fine. Then i restarted Xcode and open the original project and the problem was there again. I tried quitting Xcode, creating a new project, closing the window and opening the original one and the views where normal as you can see in this [screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/eoqow98db/). I sincerely don't understand what's going on.